# ログイン認証なしでのFireStore使用のセキュリティについて

Tags: firebase, security

FireBaseのHostingとFireStoreを使ったアプリを考えています。
セキュリティ面で懸念があり、以下の内容について見識がある方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただきたいです。
また、もし今の構成でセキュリティリスクが高い場合、おすすめの構成なども頂けるとなおありがたいです。

**【作りたいアプリ概要】**
・Webブラウザで使用するアプリ
・一般公開、ログイン認証なしで誰でも投稿可能
（・投稿をトリガに別アプリに通知をとばす）

**①「認証なし」について**
FireStoreのセキュリティルールの情報を調べると、「request.auth.uid」を前提としての例しか見当たりませんでした。
「一般公開、認証なし投稿」のアプリを作成する場合はauth情報なしで作成しても問題ないのでしょうか。
（セキュリティルールで、書き込めるデータの構造や制限は定義する予定です。）

**②悪意ある大量投稿による、無料枠の超過、料金の上昇について**
FireStoreの接続情報はjavascriptを見れば、簡単に抜き出されてしまうものとの認識です。
悪意あるユーザーの大量投稿を対策する方法はあるでしょうか。
アプリから手動での連続当行ではなく、スクリプトの書き換えなどによる大量投稿を懸念しています。
※ログイン認証がないことによって、簡単に大量アクセスされてしまうことを懸念していますが、
　ログイン認証があるアプリでも、根本的には同じ問題が発生するように思います。